# vba can't type a simple function in textbox controlsource property

Tags: vba, properties, textbox, controls

I'm new to VBA btw .. 
I built a userform with multiple textboxes that return a value based on a combo box selection.

so in the textbox **control source property**, I can write formulas like "=index( match) and stuff
but can't write something like **"=sheet1!b4+sheet1!c7"**

and I get "Couldn't set the controlsource property, invalid property value" error
my formulas are more complicated than this of course, (and they work if I type them in a normal cell) .. but it seems that I can't write any calculation sign + - * / into the controlsource property

any idea why ????

Answer (score 0):

That's because the cell is then "connected" to the text box. If you update the text box you are also updating the linked cell on `sheet1`. But if you are trying to link two cells with `=sheet1!b4+sheet1!c7` and afterwards you are changing the value in the textbox then Excel wouldn't know which cell to update. Should only Sheet1B4 get updated or only Sheet1C7? Maybe both cells get 50% of the value?

In short: one text box can have only one control source and thereby link the text box to the referenced cell.